# how to arrange arrays in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have this situation:

```
foreach ($test as $keys => $val) {    
print_r($val); echo '<br>';
}

Array ( [NAME] => John [ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 119.94 ) 
Array ( [NAME] => John [ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 119.94 ) 
Array ( [NAME] => John [ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 69.90 ) 
Array ( [NAME] => Doe [ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 119.94 ) 
Array ( [NAME] => Doe [ps_date] => 20111101 [amount] => 69.90 ) 
Array ( [NAME] => Doe [ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 199.50 )
```

what i want to do is arrange them so :

```
Array ( [NAME] => John  
             array([ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 119.94)
             array([ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 119.94)
             array([ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 69.90 ) 
Array ( [NAME] => Doe
            array([ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 119.94)
            array([ps_date] => 20111101 [amount] => 69.90)
            array([ps_date] => 20111031 [amount] => 199.50 )
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What is your current php code?

Comment: code edited with the foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function arrange_array($array) {
    $result = Array();
    foreach($array as $values) {
        $name = $values['NAME'];
        unset($values['NAME']);
        if(!is_array($result[$name])) $result[$name] = Array();                
        $result[$name][] = $values;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: mine solution is 4 times faster than deceze's solution - [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bmdWsp). And it will no produce notice errors

Comment: @Peter Sure, if run on giant arrays hundreds of times, it makes a significant difference. Under regular circumstances I'd prefer my version for brevity though. And it doesn't produce any notices either.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arranged = array();
foreach ($test as $val) {
    $arranged[$val['NAME']][] = array_diff_key($val, array('NAME' => null));
    $arranged[$val['NAME']]  += array_intersect_key($val, array('NAME' => null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($values as $item) {
  $result[$item['NAME']][] = array('ps_date' => $item['ps_date'], 'amount' => $item['amount'];
}
```